# Referring property inside from constructor using jquery return undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to access my property defined in a class constructor, from a method but it comes as undefined. 
Following is my code.

```
export class App {
  uri:string
  constructor() {
    this.uri = "bbc"
  }

  public address(){
        $( "#post" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
            window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + this.uri +".com"; 

        });

  }
}
```

and here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WNEpLx0JMnoXnHU43isl?p=preview) example.
The question was marked as duplicate but it is not, as I am inside class and I cannot use arrow function, as far as I am aware

Comment: That doesn't look like ES6. Is it TypeScript? The capitalisation of `class` and `Purchasing` seems off, and the `newUrl` type declaration should probably go inside the class body.

Comment: @Bergi Yes it is TS. updated the question and code.Sorry for typos first as I am new to the language.

Comment: @Nofel Still a duplicate though. I've added a link to a TS-specific question in the notice that appears at the top of your question. I've left Bergi's link there because the methods you can use for JS also apply to TS.

Answer (score 0):

try to insert this inside the constructor:

```
this.newUrl = this.newUrl.bind(this);
```

Comment: If I take the jquery out, It loads fine. Do you think `bind` will work?

Comment: That didn't work.